# React Router v4 nested routes not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I just upgraded to React Router v4 with a react 15.4.2 app based on a boilerplate from [Fountain JS](http://fountainjs.io/) and after reading [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/react-router-v4-complete-guide/), I wrote this:

```
// Index.js
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Route, BrowserRouter, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Main} from './app/pages/main';
import {App} from './app/pages/app';

import './index.scss';
const MainRouter = () => (
<div>
<main>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/home" component={Main}/>
        <Route path="/app" component={App}/>
      </Switch>
    </main>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <MainRouter/>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
 );

// App.jsx
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Dashboard} from './app/dashboard';
import {Money} from './app/money';
import {Header} from '../tpl/header';
import {Footer} from '../tpl/footer';

export class App extends Component {

render() {

return (
  <div>
    <Header/>
    <main>
      <Switch>

            <Route path="/app/dashboard" exact component={Dashboard}/>
            <Route path="/app/money" exact component={Money}/>
          </Switch>
        </main>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// dashboard.jsx
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>This is the Dashboard</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Navigating to http://localhost:3000/app/ seems to work fine but navigating to http://localhost:3000/app/dashboard gives 404. What could I be possibly getting wrong?

PS Even on the routes that work, adding a trailing slash will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct dashboard route at the end of App's render. **No need for another Switch over there**. So in your App.jsx file's render method :

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      ...
      <Route path="/app/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @okeziestanley Can you confirm if this solved your problem ?

Comment: **UPDATE** I was able to get through by abandoning the app and creating a fresh based on [Create React App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) and everything worked out fine. I am still not sure what the root cause of the issue is though.